# Select records having multiple values and enumerate them

Tags: php, mysql

This is what my table looks like now:

[image]

As you can see, there are multiple records, like XRAY. 
What I want to do is enumerate those to be like 
1st Xray
2nd Xray 
3rd Xray

Or any kind of enumeration.

This is the query of my current table by the way

```
"SELECT
             `incurredcharges`.`procedure_no`,
  `c`.`procedure`

FROM
  incurredcharges
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `procedure`, `procedure_no` FROM `charges`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `confinement`, `procedure_no` FROM `confinement`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `service`, `procedure_no` FROM `ultrasound`
  ) c ON `incurredcharges`.`procedure_no` = c.`procedure_no`
WHERE `incurredcharges`.`patient_no` = '$id'";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know how to prepend "1st", "2nd", etc., you can prepend 1, 2, etc.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(CASE WHEN cnt > 1 THEN CONCAT(RN,'-') ELSE '' END, t.Proc) Proc
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      @curRow:=CASE WHEN @prevRow = a.Proc THEN @curRow+1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
      a.Proc,
      @prevRow:=Proc grp
    FROM (
         SELECT Proc FROM Procedures ORDER BY Proc
      ) a JOIN (SELECT @curRow:=0) r
  ) t JOIN
  (
    SELECT Proc, COUNT(Proc) cnt 
    FROM Procedures 
    GROUP BY Proc
  ) c ON t.proc = c.proc
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f9d0/1).

Basically you need to group your procedures together giving a row number for each group.  For those records with more than one, prepend then row number.

**---EDIT---**

Given your comment, your query just needs to be placed within the main FROM (near the middle) and then you need to bring procno up to each select statement.  Here is something that should be very close, although untested:

```
SELECT
  procno,
  CONCAT(CASE WHEN cnt > 1 THEN CONCAT(RN,'-') ELSE '' END, t.Proc) Proc
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      @curRow:=CASE WHEN @prevRow = a.Proc THEN @curRow+1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
      a.Proc,
      a.Procno,
      @prevRow:=Proc grp
    FROM (    
          SELECT
            `incurredcharges`.`procedure_no` procno,
            `c`.`procedure` proc
          FROM
            incurredcharges
            INNER JOIN (
              SELECT `procedure`, `procedure_no` FROM `charges`
              UNION ALL
              SELECT `confinement`, `procedure_no` FROM `confinement`
              UNION ALL
              SELECT `service`, `procedure_no` FROM `ultrasound`
            ) c ON `incurredcharges`.`procedure_no` = c.`procedure_no`
          WHERE `incurredcharges`.`patient_no` = '$id'
          ORDER BY `c`.`procedure`
      ) a 
          JOIN (SELECT @curRow:=0) r
  ) t JOIN
  (
          SELECT
            `incurredcharges`.`procedure_no` procno,
            `c`.`procedure` proc, Count(*) cnt
          FROM
            incurredcharges
            INNER JOIN (
              SELECT `procedure`, `procedure_no` FROM `charges`
              UNION ALL
              SELECT `confinement`, `procedure_no` FROM `confinement`
              UNION ALL
              SELECT `service`, `procedure_no` FROM `ultrasound`
            ) c ON `incurredcharges`.`procedure_no` = c.`procedure_no`
          WHERE `incurredcharges`.`patient_no` = '$id'
          GROUP BY `incurredcharges`.`procedure_no`,
            `c`.`procedure`
  ) c ON t.proc = c.proc
```

Good luck.

Comment: That is perfect. But I am having trouble incorporating it with my sql query.

Comment: @jeffmangum -- Glad to hear this can work, but sorry about the trouble. I edited my response -- see above.  Let me know how it works for you.  If you could build a Fiddle, I could test it, but this should be fairly close.  Best of luck (and don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you) :)

Comment: @jeffmangum -- you'll also need to update the last query which is used to get the count -- I'll edit again now...

Comment: What is `Proc`? Is it a new variable cause I don't have a field name like that. It's extra confusing cause I used different tables.

Comment: @jeffmangum -- it's what I used in my Fiddle as the column name.  So I used it as an alias to your Procedure column (so I didn't have to change a lot of code) -- you can use Procedure if you'd prefer and update the code accordingly.

Comment: @jeffmangum -- you might be better off creating a View out of your main query -- that way, you can use my original code with few changes.  That might make it easier for you.

Comment: So it's the field for the name of the procedure? In my case its pretty tricky since the procedure names are in 3 tables. And their names aren't `Procedure` but its `confinement`, `procedure`, and `service`. I wish I could go back to that time I made the structure.

Comment: @jeffmangum -- Looking at your original query, it's the c.procedure field (the result of the union) -- make sense?

Comment: I changed the very beginning `SELECT procno` to `SELECT c.proc`. Theres no more error. Sql has been executed successfully but there are no results. (im sorry if i dont understand fully your query. its 4:30am here and i literally have no sleep and working non-stop)

Comment: @jeffmangum -- OUCH!  Sorry to hear -- been there before... Any chance you could be a Fiddle and I could help you with it -- hard to do it without seeing it.  Sounds like you're really close though.

Comment: I'm working on it. I'll add all the needed tables. Is there a way i could import my .sql?

Comment: @jeffmangum -- I don't believe you can import -- you can create scripts and they should work though...  Looks like you have 3 tables -- just need some sample data with those tables...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d511 I included the 4 tables. the 3 are the procedures. and the other one is the table for what i want to retrieve data from.

Comment: @jeffmangum -- I think that fiddle is missing your column names.

Comment: I did include the column names. in the "text to ddl" button, I entered the table name then pasted the values. Oh wait, you mean the COLUMN name.. How do I supply the column name? Cause what i did was copy from a CSV format i exported from phpmyadmin

Comment: @jeffmangum -- can you easily update to the correct column names?  I'm not 100% on my end.

Comment: I'm currently working on it. Also, thank you by the way. I'm glad someone's helping me.

Comment: Ok wow. Just when I finished making the tables on Fiddle, I spotted the error, it's the `$id`. Of course it wouldnt return any result on sql. Now its working. Thanks again!
edit: the problem now is that it only shows 1 on duplicate entries. Not 1, 2 ,3, etc.

Comment: @jeffmangum -- no worries bud -- glad you got it working!!! I've had those late nights before.  Best of luck!

Comment: @jeffmangum -- btw -- if the answer helped you out, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkbox next to it.  no worries though!

Comment: I edited my comment and turns out theres a little problem. It's not showing, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. Its just 1 on all duplicate entries

Comment: Thats weird. On the fiddle, it works fine. It's enumerated. But on my mysql, its not.

Comment: @jeffmangum -- no clue then buddy -- gotta be something, probably really small.  Wish you the best!

Comment: But its the exact same code from the fiddle to sql. I keep on copy-pasting it. :(  Could it be on my PHP code?

Comment: Its ok. :( I just restarted my pc but its still the same. Why must bad things happen to good people ugh